# Angularjs create directive dynamically with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to know is there any way to create dynamic directive with `ng-repeat`. Something, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="document in documents">
    <div document.name></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use attributes to do that. For example:

```
    <div ng-repeat="document in documents">
       <document-viewer name="document.name"></document-viewer>
    </div>
```

and

```
    var app = angular.module("documents", []);

    app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.documents = [
            {id:1, name:'document1'},
            {id:2, name:'document2'}
        ];
    });

    app.directive("documentViewer", function() {
        return {
           scope: {
                //attribute name will match the name passed from your view,
                //and you will be able to use it on your template or logic
                name: "="
           },
           //Add your template here:
           template: '<div><button ng-click="openDocument(name);"></div>',
           //Add your logic here:
           link: function(scope, element, attrs){ ... }
        }
    });
```

I don't know if that answers your question, but you are not making clear what is it you are trying to achieve.

Have a look at the following videos as they might come handy for you when dealing with directives and isolate scope:

http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication

http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding

http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-attribute-binding

http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-two-way-binding

Comment: No, I want link directive dynamically with objects' name. In your case, I create directives with names .directive('document1') and .directive('document2') and then in ng-repeat I link some <div document.name> with that directive.